# Is it possible to add two buttons as subviews to a table cell for iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add two buttons to each cell in a tableview, but when I add them as subviews, only one of the buttons is clickable as the logic would dictate.

> btn1.frame = CGRectMake(210,4,100,40);
>
> btn2.frame = CGRectMake(250,4,100, 40);
>
> [cell.contentView addSubview:btn2];
>
> [cell.contentView addSubview:btn1];

Is there way to add two buttons and be able to click both?

Comment: What is the size (frame) of `cell`, `btn1` and `btn2`? Do you add selectors to each of the buttons?

Comment: Yes, but for this you'll probably need to create a custom cell.

Comment: I added the size of the buttons. I did not set the size of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons layers intersect. Look at your frames:

1. x = 210, y = 4, width = 100, height = 40: left corner: (210, 4), right corner (310, 4)
2. x = 250, y = 4, width = 100, height = 40: left corner: (250, 4), right corner (350, 4)

So now you should change your buttons `frames` so that they won't intersect.

Some text from Apple Docs:

CGRectMake
Returns a rectangle with the specified coordinate and size values.

```
CGRect CGRectMake (
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   CGFloat width,
   CGFloat height
);
```